# Trouble reading txt PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I to generate queries from a txt file, but php just take the last line and return the result.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function sql_txt($arg,$arg1)
{
    $sql =  "SELECT name, count(name), COUNT(CASE WHEN TAG = {$arg1} THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)from softwares s, accountinfo a
                where s.hardware_id = a.HARDWARE_ID and name like '{$arg}%'
                group by name;";

    return($sql);
}

function lector($arg1)
{
    require("conexion.php");
    $software = fopen("software.txt",'r');
    $read = fread($software,filesize("software.txt"));
    fclose($software);
    $softwares = split("\n", $read);
    $array_software = array();
    foreach($softwares as $nombre)
    {
        $sql = sql_txt($nombre,$arg1);
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
        {
            $array_software[] =  $row;
        }   
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    return($array_software);
}
print_r(lector("'VRA-BIB'"));
?>
```

When i execute this on my pc all it's okay, but when i move the file to other machine (with the same version of php) just take the last line of txt.

there ir a example of txt

```
Microsoft Project
WinZip
WinRar
Adobe Photoshop
Adobe Dreamweaver
Adobe Flash
Adobe Acrobat
TeamViewer
Visual Studio 2010
Visual Studio 2012
Sybase PowerDesigner
Sybase PowerBuilder
Microsoft Visio
```

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: **warning** mysql_ functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: When you say that you move the file to another machine, do you mean you are running the script on Machine A and the file is on Machine B? Or do you mean you move the entire script and file on to Machine B?

Comment: **warning** `split` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: I move the entire script and file on to machine B

Comment: Do the 2 machines have the same operating system?

Comment: both machines have linux, machina A -> Ubuntu, machine B -> Mint. The code run perfect on mint machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of script after the PHP tag:

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```